# increasing accessToken life if used if used within accesstokenlife in idenity server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I would like to increase my Expiry time for my access token if it used within the acessTokenLifeTime or else expire it as per acessTokenLifeTime given.

In my scenario the AccessTokenLifeTime is 6 minutes. But if the user uses the access token within the 6 minutes an extra 6 minutes should be added to the AccessTokenLifeTime. I hve tried the below code but the AccessToken never expires.

```
 ////Grant Type:Resource Owner Password  
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = SecurityConfig.PublicApiClientId,
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                    //no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
                    //secret for authentication
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret(SecurityConfig.PublicApiClientPassword.Sha256())
                    },

                    AllowOfflineAccess = false,
                 AccessTokenLifetime = 360, 
                  SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 360,
                  RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,

                    //scope that client has access to 
                    AllowedScopes = { SecurityConfig.PublicApiResourceId }
                }

            };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how things work.

When a user requests a new access token the access token lifetime is set decided by the AccessTokenLifetime of the client.  The user can use this access token as many times as they want with in this lifetime.  A new token is not generated for the user every time they use it.  THe user only gets a new access token when the request a new one using a refresh token or they login.

The only way to alter the life time of generated access tokens would be to alter the AccessTokenLifetime on the client which would then alter it for all the users of the client not just the single one.

You cant have AccessTokenLifetime  per user or per access token like that.   You can read more about this here [Access token lifetime](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-lifetime/)